# Tidy way to delete image from Gtk::TreeStore

Tags: c++, gtk, gtktreeview

I have an dialog window with Gtk::TreeView. This dialod shows main filesystem tree
and provides option to select folders on the disk. When user selects some folder, I am
adding an Gtk::Stock image to the row that represents that folder.

To do this, I have created an Gtk::CellRendererPixbuf associated with the last column of my tree:

```
//appending columns
directory_tree.append_column("Folder List", dir_columns.name);
Gtk::TreeViewColumn *column = directory_tree.get_column(0);
if(column) column->set_expand(true);
Gtk::CellRendererPixbuf *cell = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::CellRendererPixbuf);
directory_tree.append_column("", *cell);
column = directory_tree.get_column(1);
if(column) column->add_attribute(cell->property_stock_id(), dir_columns.stock_id);
```

Link to this bit of code: https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Imagine/blob/master/gui/dialogs.cpp#L47

Gtk::CellRendererPixbuf 'translates' Gtk::StockId found in 'dir_columns.stock_id'
to an image located in tree. When I add image to row like this:

```
//selecting folder
(*folder)[fs_columns.stock_id] = Gtk::StockID(Gtk::Stock::FIND).get_string();
(*folder)[fs_columns.included] = true;
```

everything is ok, but when I try to delete the image this way:

```
//unselecting folder
(*folder)[fs_columns.stock_id] = "";
(*folder)[fs_columns.included] = false;
```

the image correctly disappears, but there are some errors in command line like this (this is not the exact message, I will post it when I will be able to launch my application):

```
(imagine:9376): Gtk-WARNING **: Gtk StockId not found
```

Of course the reason of the warning is obvious (there is no StockId item associated with blank name), however my question is: Is there a way to delete an image from Gtk::TreeView row which would not generate any Gtk warnings?

Code where i deselect folder is here:
https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Imagine/blob/master/core/core.cpp#L207

Thank you very much in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `visible` property to false if you want to get rid of the image, instead of the `stock-id` property.

Comment: Thank you! I have not noticed that i can control visibility of each cell using CellRendererPixbuf. The solution was to delete `(*folder)[fs_columns.stock_id] = "";` and to add that line of code: https://github.com/mc-suchecki/Imagine/blob/master/gui/dialogs.cpp#L56 (happily I had a column with bool value indicating the visibility of an image).